# AWS S3 ACL for allowing access for all users or roles, etc. in a specific account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

According to the Documentation: [Granting permissions to multiple accounts with added conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-1) it is possible to create with the entry:

```
Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root","arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"]}
```

just access for all the users inside this account. But unfortunately it is not working. When putting single users there the access for that User from that different account is working. But with all and the `root` option is does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> But with all and the root option is does not work.

This is because the admins of these accounts also have to **add permissions to IAM users/roles** to access the bucket. In other words, adding `arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root` to a bucket policy is not enough. The individual IAM users or roles from `111122223333` also need IAM permissions to access the bucket.

Comment: But why do I need to give again IAM permissions when the account root line should do the trick? Then why do i need then the first entry?

Comment: @Maik Because it does not work like that. The permissions on the root do not automatically flow to all iam users or roles.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I need to read deeper into that Policy Management, as I am still confused. Some documentation states that this is the way.
If I find something else I will let you know :-) Have a great day. Cheers